# Retrieve author / owner of term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am loading a term and trying to get the author or owner of the term, however I can not see any function under the [Term Class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/class/Term/8.4.x)

On the other hand I can see the translation author being present on the edit page.

Any way to retrieve author for Term?

Comment: There is no owner being set on Term entities by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of Drupal core. There's a module which provides this capability for D7,  [Taxonomy Term Author Info](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_authoring_info) but it's not been officially ported to D8 although there is an unofficial port at https://github.com/worthingtonlibraries/term_authoring_info

Answer (score 1):

As [Alfred Armstrong](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/13727/alfred-armstrong) states this is not possible as part of Drupal core as the default fields for Taxonomy doesn't include a User field.

However, in D8 Taxonomy is just another entity type so it would be a fairly simply process to add a new field at Structure >> Taxonomy >> {{ Name }} >> Manage fields with the type being Reference >> User